# How to copy a matrix in a bigger matrix in CUDA

Tags: cuda, cublas, cula

I want to setup a big matrix on my GPU to solve the according equation system with CULA.

Some numbers for you, to understand the problem:

```
big matrix:     400x400
small matrices: 200x200
```

Now I want to copy every quarter `(100x100)` of the small matrix to a specific part of the second matrix.

I found two possible but obviously slow examples: `cublasSetMatrix` and `cublasGetMatrix` support the specification of a leading dimension, so I could put the parts, where I want them, but have to copy the matrix back to the host.
The other example would be `cudaMemcpy`, which doesn't support leading dimensions. Here I could copy every single row/column (at the moment I am unsure what is used by this routine, data comes from Fortran) by hand. But this way, I should get a big overhead...

Is there a better way than writing my own kernel, to copy the matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may revise your Q. I guess you are finding a way that can both change the leading dimension and do D2Dcpy.

There is a routine `cudaMemcpy2D()` can do that as shown in [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g17f3a55e8c9aef5f90b67cdf22851375).

Comment: This routine is, what I was looking for. Btw, I don't intend to change my leading dimension. I only needed a way to specify the leading dimension so that a certain gap is taken account, while looking at linear memory.